# How to only run useEffect when something was added to array with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of alerts stored in a state:

```
const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);
```

I push to this list all errors and notifications that then show up in an alert box. What I want is to automatically pop an added alert after `3000ms`. Here is what I have to do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setAlerts([...alerts].splice(0, 1));
  }, 3000);
}, [alerts]);
```

However what I get is an infinite loop that is triggered because even when I remove from that alert it changes. So I guess I only need to fire the code above when something was added to the alerts array. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your actual desired behaviour? A reasonable answer was given below to use `alerts.length` but you say this isn't what you want. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Adam, my aim is to show alert notificans when something is saved or produced an error and hide this alert in X seconds. Alerts are also stacked if there is more than one alert at a time.

Comment: So what's wrong with using `alerts.length` instead of `alerts` as a dependency on your effect?

Comment: @Adam, because I remove items from the alerts array after X seconds which fires useEffect && setTimeout again so I get an infinite loop.

Comment: would you ever have more than one alert showing at a single time?

Comment: You don't get in an infinite loop, because after all the alerts are removed then `alerts.length` doesn't change. If you do get stuck in an infinite loop, then it's because you're doing something else and haven't shown the code for it.

Comment: @Adam, Probably, but anyway setTimeout should only be fired when something is added to the array, with array.length it is also fired when something is removed from the array (with the setTimeout code) so it messes things up.

Comment: @GBWDev. Yes, it should show as many errors or notifications as I have removing each of them after X seconds one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an effect:

```
const [alerts,setAlerts] = useState([]);

const handleAddAlert = (alert) => {
   setTimeout(() => setAlerts(alerts.filter(a => a !== alert)),3000);
   setAlerts([...alerts,alert]);
}


// instead of calling `setAlerts` in your code down here, call `handleAddAlert` with the alert
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you might want to handle this a little more manually.  Something I like to use for this type of thing is the `usePrevious` hook from [useHooks](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/).

```js
// Hook
function usePrevious(value) {
  // The ref object is a generic container whose current property is mutable ...
  // ... and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class
  const ref = useRef();

  // Store current value in ref
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); // Only re-run if value changes

  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
}
```

When you fire the effect, I would check the length to make sure its larger than the previous length, something like this:

```
const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

const previousAlerts = usePrevious(alerts);

useEffect(() => {
  if (alerts.length > previousAlerts.length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlerts([...alerts].splice(0, 1));
    }, 3000);
  }
}, [alerts]);
```

I know this answer might not be as simple as you'd like but something I've realized with hooks is that sometimes you have to be pretty explicit with their use.  And the `usePrevious` can solve a lot of problems like this.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on where and how you are changing your alerts array. Usually you would have some alert source, such as a response coming from ajax or something and you can use a separate state for keeping the raw objects.

```
// this would hold row alerts
const [rawAlerts, setRawAlerts] = useState([]);

//This would hold alerts that you want to display and you only update them in useEffect
const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

// Here you would update alerts only when rawAlerts gets updated
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setAlerts([...rawAlerts].splice(0, 1));
  }, 3000);
}, [rawAlerts]);
```

Comment: The last part is wrong a little cause you update rawAlerts again, but I got the idea. Thanks!

Comment: You update the was alerts once you have new data for the alerts to display and once it gets updated, useEffect will update the main alerts with the data from rawAlers which will get displayed somewhere. Unless I misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I am dumb I see `setAlert` now.